# Modalpopup in nested Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am working on a web application, where I have a nested Gridview. On editing the row of the child Gridview, I need to edit the child and parent gridview in a modal popup[image]

I was planning on doing something like this:

```
Protected Sub ParentGridview_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ParentGridview.SelectedIndexChanged

        For Each row As GridViewRow In ParentGridview.Rows

            Dim ChilGridviw As GridView = DirectCast(row.FindControl("ChilGridviw "), GridView)


'some more code here

        Next

    End Sub
```

Any assistance will be highly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Not sure what's your question. Do you want to have the edit form in a modal pop up? if so, what I would do is to invoke a formview control when you click the child gridview. Pass the current ID to the formview and open it in Edit Mode. There are many example on the web how to do this.

Comment: Yes exactly. Can you please share a link or two. Thanks

Comment: http://www.programming-free.com/2013/09/gridview-crud-bootstrap-modal-popup.html This should work for you.